# Prevent Win10 using a given drive for temp or other files

Tags: hard-drive, noise

I recently added  large TB hard drive (F:), seems to be working fine except it makes a lot of noise when the drive head seeks any where.  The annoying thing it seems to be every 5 -> 15 seconds continually.   Trying to figure out what is causing it in order to stop it.

This is where I'm stuck.  Tried running Process Monitor and watching for file activity, nothing.  Searching some comments about disable searching/indexing. Stopping Windows search and indexing, no change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: Seems like you're seeing the Windows disk-status request. Try in *Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings*, under *Hard disk > Turn off hard disk after* to set a time period of a few minutes. If you have this setting, then after the specified amount of idle time the disk will sleep.

Comment: @John - Given the similarities between Windows 10 and Windows 11 I am not sure how upgrading to Windows 11 would solve the author’s problem.

Comment: @harrymc  To be a bit more specific than the title of my post..
Windows is:
Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.4170)

Comment: @harrymc   
Also tried turning the drive off after 1 minute, as the first step, then "Wrte Cache off. Didn't help appears something is pinging f:  My temp is "c:\tmp" and/or c:\temp.  Searched the registry for F:\, found nothing and in windoZe file defender/anti-malware i excluded f:\.

Comment: I had a similar case, but after some time the noise stopped (after days? weeks? I don't remember). Apparently Windows or the disk's firmware finished whatever task they were doing.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the info, sure you'd agree i've been looking at the right stuff, procmon(64) -- tried both, checked most everyting...   What i'm seeing now it appears Firefox might be the culpit, did find one setting and set it, seems it helped and if FF isn't running sure seems the drive isn't accessed anymore...  Anyway thanks for the help, as a sanity check just wanted to make sure i didn't miss something...  Have a great day.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issue has self-resolved at some point, and we cannot know what the root cause was.